# Update a value in one column based on a criteria in another column, using tidyr but with less typing than base R, to include later in a pipe

Tags: r, dplyr, replace, tidyr

Simple situation.
Using base R

```
iris_df <- iris 
iris_df$Sepal.Length[iris_df$Species == "setosa"] <- NA
```

Using `dplyr`

```
iris_df <- iris %>% mutate(Sepal.Length = if_else(Species == "setosa", NA_real_, Sepal.Length))
```

I don't mind the extra typing in the `tidyr` version if that's what I have to do (I want to embed this in a pipe). But when something takes more typing in `tidyr` than base R, I feel I must be missing something? Is there a shorter syntax in `tidyr`?

Comment: Less typing? `is.na(iris_df$Sepal.Length) <- iris_df$Species == "setosa"`. But base R...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option using `dplyr` that is 6 characters shorter than `if_else()`

```
iris %>% 
  mutate(Sepal.Length = replace(Sepal.Length, Species == "setosa", NA))
```

Edit:

This one is the exact same length if we remove whitespace:

```
iris %>% 
  mutate(Sepal.Length = na_if(Species, "setosa"))
```

```r
nchar('iris_df$Sepal.Length[iris_df$Species=="setosa"]<-NA')
#> [1] 51

nchar('iris%>%mutate(Sepal.Length=na_if(Species,"setosa"))')
#> [1] 51
```